# Unity Terrain suddenly causing low FPS

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this map system in our game, players check which map to play and in the next scene a terrain prefab is spawned accordingly.

Problem: I used to have 110+ FPS (with V-Sync disabled), but now FPS won't go above 20, I used trial and error to find out the culprit and it is the **terrain**, once disabled in playmode, FPS shoots up to it's old result.

What I tried:

- Baking lighting.
- Lowering terrain details density, count, you name it.
- Lowering terrain width/length/detail resolution per patch/detail resolution etc.
- Disabled realtime GI, baked the scene and still.
- Disabling shadows everywhere.
- Restarting unity and PC.
- As per comments I attached a screenshot of profiling [image: Image from Gyazo]

Note that FPS was 100+ with all above features at high values.
Also note that I didn't upgrade unity to another version, am having low FPS on same device/unity version and day that I had high FPS on !!

What do you think happened ?

What else do you think I should try ?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you profiled it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I attached a screenshot of the profiler, hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After alot of trial and error, I had my Game Window in Editor resolution to 4k.
Setting it back to 2k brought back the FPS to 100+.